# Html5 canvas not sizing to fill parent div

Tags: css, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to make a square canvas. I want to do this with css so that the canvas is instantly sized when the page loads.

To make it square I am wrapping it in a div and styling it as follows:

http://jsfiddle.net/evopgwzd/

```
body {
    background-color: blue;
}

#wrap {
    width: 40%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 40%;
}

canvas {
    background-color: white;
    width:100%;
    height:100%
}
```

However, nothing is showing up. If I set the wrap's css to be hard-coded width sizes, either pixels or percents, the canvas displays. I suspect I'm missing something simple but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're setting height 0 to wrap the height of canvas is 0 too and shows nothing
try this

```css
body {
    background-color: blue;
}

#wrap {
    width: 40vh;
    height: 40vh;
}

canvas {
    background-color: white;
    width:100%;
    height:100%
}
```

Comment: You left the height still at zero. The background yellow was to demonstrate what I wanted the white canvas to replace.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Change both, width and height to 40vh and delete the padding-bottom attribute.

Comment: That seems to have worked, I'll just need to add a resize listener, no big deal.

How does that work? What does vh do?

Comment: vh gets the height of the device